# Gridgain visor and Wan replication available only on Enterprise?

Tags: gridgain

Am I right in saying that Gridgain visor and Wan replication can only be used on an Enterprise subscription?

http://www.gridgain.org/support/ suggests they are.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datacenter Replication (DR) and GUI-based Visor management are part of enterprise edition.

However, GridGain Command Line Visor management (http://atlassian.gridgain.com/wiki/display/GG60/Command+Line+Interface) is part of open source edition.

Additionally, some of the other cool features provided as open source include different language connectivity (like C++, C#, HTTP), and off-heap storage.

Comment: Having a community edition was exactly what was missing. Very happy to learn about the opensource version.